# Add Area 51 Link to Accounts Tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, user-accounts, linked-accounts

Now that Area 51 is public, there should be an [Area 51 link to my profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/30?tab=accounts#tab-top).

Comment: Enjoy your new 10k powers ♪

Comment: @Grace, Thanks! I can't believe I have waited so long to push for 10k on meta.

Answer (score 4):

And can we have a link on the bottom of the page as well (right at the bottom of this page where you can see the links to stackoverflow.com, api/apps, careers, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy your information from Area 51 to any of the Trilogy sites either. Firefox saved fields/ cut and paste are the only current options.