# Add an Area 51 link to the footer of the other sites?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, design

The closest question I can find is this one, which asks for an Area 51 link in our profiles.
[Add Area 51 Link to Accounts Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53927/add-area-51-link-to-accounts-tab)

I would also like to see the link to Area 51 in the footer of the other sites, down where the links to SO, careers, serverfault, etc. are located. I use those links to switch between sites, but maybe I'm weird in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link has been added to the footer.