# Area51 account not shown in "Related Accounts" on others site

Tags: bug, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add Area 51 Link to Accounts Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53927/add-area-51-link-to-accounts-tab)

On others SE site than area51 in the accounts tab of a user the Area51 account is not listed in "Related Accounts".
May be it's wanted, may be not but this prevent to copy profile from area51 to others site

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53927/add-area-51-link-to-accounts-tab